# Number of different positions of rooks on chessboard

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, discrete-mathematics, chess

I know that this topic as been mentioned before, but no accurate answer has been provided.

Suppose we have to place $n$ rooks on $n \times n$ chessboard so that no one attacks another. How to count the number of different ways to place them up to rotations of the chessboard?

I have been trying the Burnside's lemma but did not obtain satisfactory results...

Comment: You should definitely add links to any previous questions on this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, are you sure that on the wikipedia there is a solution to the problem up to rotation (in the last paragraph) ? Note that I only focus on rotations not reflections...

Comment: true, this complication is not in the Wikipage; it is mentioned (without solution) in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459248/ways-to-place-n-non-attacking-rooks-on-an-n2-square-board

Comment: Numerical counts are now given in http://oeis.org/A263685

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the first complete solution to this kind of problem was worked out by Édouard Lucas in section 128 of his textbook on number theory:

- Édouard Lucas, [Théorie des Nombres](https://archive.org/stream/thoriedesnombre00lucagoog#page/n245/mode/2up) (1891)

Notice that he considers solutions different up to rotations *and reflections*, so you have to slightly modify the argument. Here is an outline:

You begin with the $n!$ total solutions, and consider the group of symmetries $\Gamma$ of the chessboard you are interested in. Those are:

$\Gamma_1$: Identity

$\Gamma_2$:Rotation by $\pi$ radians.

$\Gamma_3$:Rotation by $\pm \pi/2$ radians.

If we denote $\sigma_n$ the number of differente solutions (under those symmetries), then $\sigma_n$ is the number of orbits of $\Gamma$ on the set of the $n!$ solutions, so that you can now apply Burnside's lemma.

Now, $\Gamma_1=n!$ and $\Gamma_2=(n/2)!2^{n/2}$.

Also $\Gamma_3=(2m)!/m!$ if $n=4m$ or $n=4m+1$, and $\Gamma_3=0$ otherwise.

From here you can easily count the number of solutions.

For a clearer and more modern exposition of the solution considering also reflections, you can consult:

- Robert W. Robinson, [Counting arrangements of bishops](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0097382) (1976)

Comment: I have been trying for a while but I cannot understand the formulas for Gamma2 and Gamma3 - could you please clarify how did you get these solutions invariant of the rotations ? Also, why the result is specific for the value of n ?